# Dependency Injection issue with StructureMap Container

Tags: asp.net, angularjs

I'm using Structure Map for DI in ASP.net MVC and calling actions from angularjs service but the constructor is not getting called to which I have injected dependency while parameter less constructor is getting called.

It is not giving any error.
I have configured it for the first time in the project.

Code:-

```
public class StructureMapControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
    {
        public override IController CreateController(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName)
        {
            var controllerType = base.GetControllerType(requestContext, controllerName);
            return controllerType == null ? null : ObjectFactory.GetInstance(controllerType) as IController;
        }
    }

public class SiteConfig
    {
        public static void BootStrap()
        {
            ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
            {
                x.AddRegistry<fullpath.BusinessRegistry>();
            });

            //Controller Factory
            ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new StructureMapControllerFactory());
        }
    }
```

In Application_Start() called BootStrap() method.

```
public BusinessRegistry()
     {
        For<IDemoBL>().Use<DemoBL>();
     }
```

Comment: Can you please share me a few code snippets to find a feasible solution for you?

Comment: @praveenkumars, I have added code.